# Cannot install any R packages?

Tags: r, unix, installation, package

I am using R 3.2.2 on a UNIX server (this is installed to my HOME).

Any package that I try to install returns an error message like this:

```
install.packages('knitr')
Warning: unable to access index for repository
https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib
Warning message:
package ‘knitr’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)
```

I've also tried downloading the package source and installing manually, but that doesn't work:

```
install.packages('/home/baker/knitr_1.11.tar.gz',repos= NULL,type='source')
ERROR: dependencies ‘evaluate’, ‘digest’, ‘formatR’, ‘highr’, ‘markdown’,     ‘stringr’, ‘yaml’ are not available for package ‘knitr’
* removing ‘/home/baker/R/lib64/R/library/knitr’
Warning message:
In install.packages("/home/baker/knitr_1.11.tar.gz", repos = NULL,  :
 installation of package ‘/home/baker/knitr_1.11.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

This is obviously a super frustrating problem...any ideas? I'm at a total loss.

Comment: what mirror are you using, the second should work by turning off dependencies

Comment: Also, are you connected to any vpn?, If you manually install packages vi R CMD INSTALL, please make sure to install dependencies first.